# html radio hack plus same page anchor (link)

Tags: html, css

Below is my code, it works as desired. however to make it work I had to add `onclick` events to the `label` elements, is there a way to get both the links to fire and radio toggle to fire without using `onclick` code?

it is fine to not have have `label` elements but I was unable to toggle the `radios` without them.

my **desired result** is for the code below to have the same functionality without javascript in inline `onclick` events in the 3 `.magic-label` elements. so desirably no javascript to make this work, and I only desire `label` elements if required for the solution.

thank you for any possible help or solutions.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

header {
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3.5rem;
  z-index: 10;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li:nth-child( 3n + 1),
#main .panel:nth-child( 3n + 1) {
  background: rgb( 0, 180, 255);
}

ul li:nth-child( 3n + 2),
#main .panel:nth-child( 3n + 2) {
  background: rgb( 255, 65, 180);
}

ul li:nth-child( 3n + 3),
#main .panel:nth-child( 3n + 3) {
  background: rgb( 0, 255, 180);
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0px;
  margin: 0 0rem;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  padding: 0.3rem 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 2px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

ul li a,
.magic-label {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ( 0);
  transform: translateZ( 0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.panel h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 64px;
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 200px;
  top: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}


/*
 *Scrolling
 */

a[ id="servicios"]:target ~ #main article.panel {
  -webkit-transform: translateY( 0px);
  transform: translateY( 0px);
}

a[ id="galeria"]:target ~ #main article.panel {
  -webkit-transform: translateY( -500px);
  transform: translateY( -700px);
}

a[ id="contacto"]:target ~ #main article.panel {
  -webkit-transform: translateY( -1000px);
  transform: translateY( -1400px);
}


/* special code for toggling links*/

a.clicked {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: inherit;
}

.radio-button {
  display: none;
}

#serv-radio:checked~#magic .serv,
#gale-radio:checked~#magic .gale,
#cont-radio:checked~#magic .cont {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="serv-radio" class="radio-button" name="content-magic" checked="checked" />
<input type="radio" id="gale-radio" class="radio-button" name="content-magic" value="" />
<input type="radio" id="cont-radio" class="radio-button" name="content-magic" value="" />

<a id="servicios"></a>
<a id="galeria"></a>
<a id="contacto"></a>

<header id="magic" class="nav">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label for="serv-radio" class="magic-label serv" onclick="document.getElementById('serv-radio').checked='checked'">
          <a class="clicked" href="#servicios">
            Servicios
          </a>
        </label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="gale-radio" class="magic-label gale" onclick="document.getElementById('gale-radio').checked='checked'">
          <a class="clicked" href="#galeria" >
            Galeria
          </a>
        </label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="cont-radio" class="magic-label cont" onclick="document.getElementById('cont-radio').checked='checked'">
          <a class="clicked" href="#contacto">
            Contacta nos
          </a>
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<section id="main">
  <article class="panel" id="servicios">
    <h1> Nuestros Servicios</h1>
  </article>

  <article class="panel" id="galeria">
    <h1> Mustra de nuestro trabajos</h1>
  </article>

  <article class="panel" id="contacto">
    <h1> Pongamonos en contacto</h1>
  </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that since you are already using hash-fragments to keep track of state, you do not need to use the checkbox hack for your setup.

Here is your set up with all the radio buttons and labels removed:

```css
html,
body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
}

body {
overflow: hidden;
}

header {
background: #fff;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 3.5rem;
z-index: 10;
}

nav {
width: 100%;
padding-top: 0.5rem;
}

nav ul {
list-style: none;
width: inherit;
margin: 0;
}

ul li:nth-child(3n - 2),
#main .panel:nth-child(3n - 2) {
background-color: rgb( 0, 180, 255);
}

ul li:nth-child(3n - 1),
#main .panel:nth-child(3n - 1) {
background-color: rgb( 255, 65, 180);
}

ul li:nth-child(3n),
#main .panel:nth-child(3n) {
background-color: rgb( 0, 255, 180);
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

ul li a {
display: inline-block;
padding: 0.3rem 0.5rem;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
}

.panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  z-index: 0;
  transform: translateZ( 0);
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.panel h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 64px;
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 200px;
  top: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}


/* Scrolling */
a[id="servicios"]:target ~ #main article.panel {transform: translateY( 0px);}
a[id="galeria"]:target ~ #main article.panel {transform: translateY( -700px);}
a[id="contacto"]:target ~ #main article.panel {transform: translateY( -1400px);}


/* Nav Item Text Color */
header [href="#servicios"],
a[id="galeria"]:target ~ header [href="#galeria"],
a[id="contacto"]:target ~ header [href="#contacto"] {color: rgb(255, 0, 0);}

a[id="galeria"]:target ~ header [href="#servicios"],
a[id="contacto"]:target ~ header [href="#servicios"]
{color: rgb(255, 255, 255);}
```

```html
<a id="servicios"></a>
<a id="galeria"></a>
<a id="contacto"></a>

<header>
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#servicios">Servicios</a></li>
<li><a href="#galeria" >Galeria</a></li>
<li><a href="#contacto">Contacta nos</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>

<section id="main">
<article class="panel">
<h1> Nuestros Servicios</h1>
</article>

<article class="panel">
<h1> Mustra de nuestro trabajos</h1>
</article>

<article class="panel">
<h1> Pongamonos en contacto</h1>
</article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the following `Javascript`:

```
$(".magic-label").click(function () {
    var label_id = $(this).attr('for'); //gets the *for* attrbute from the label
    document.getElementById(label_id).checked='checked';
});
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sreetamdas/cq8pqpov/)

Comment: I am trying to accomplish this task without using javascript. your answer uses jQuery which is even more overhead then just javascript, also this answer doesn't work, when you click a link it doesn't change the color to red.